# How do I migrate a EC2 instance in VPC to Classic EC2?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2

I wanted to migrate my EC2 instance which is in a VPC to a classic EC2 instance.

Is this possible?

What are the steps I need to follow?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the Amazon [Documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/launching-instance.html)
If your account supports EC2 Classic you can make an AMI of the existing instance, and launch that AMI into EC2 Classic.

To find out whether your account supports EC2 Classic look under AWS Management Console -> EC2 Service, under Supported Platforms.

[image]